# Unable to list regex protected branch using Gitlab API

Tags: shell, curl, gitlab

I am trying to get GitLab protected branches of a project using curl API request, getting all the relevant branches of type "xyz", "xyz-*".
But I am unable to get the branch that has a "/" in its name.

Using below curl request which is failing for branch "release/R*" :

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" "https://xyz.gitlab.com/tools/gitlab/api/v4/projects/492/protected_branches/'release/R*'"`

It gives an output `{"error":"404 Not Found"}`
Need help to get the output for all the branches, irrespective of the regex, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use in a curl request the name of a branch that contains `/` you need to use its encoded form `%2F`

Change

```
release/R
```

To

```
release%2FR
```

To test it, try to query for a single branch (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#get-single-repository-branch)

For a branch with name E.g. `release/Rated`

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" "https://example.com/gitlab/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/branches/release%2FRated"
```

Comment: thank you for quick help. This helped me to resolve my issue.

Comment: @user18243280 If this indeed resolved the issue, please approve and/or upvote the answer to help future users spot the solution to the problem.

Instructions on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers